# Toast can't be "shown()" in a non-activity class

Tags: android, toast

I don't know if you can launch a toast from a non-activity class, a class that isn't the activity itself. I want to use my toast in my Input Filter class so I first tried passing the whole activity to the other class but that severely failed. So I decided to pass the context itself to the non-activity class, in this case it is InputFilterMinMax. From there I use that context to attempt to display the Toast to the current activity. My question is, is this possible and if so why is my application crashing once my toast attempts to launch. Thanks.

```
package com.TechDigy.parabolicmotion;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private int min, max;
    Context context;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
        this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(Context context2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        context = context2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {   
        try {
            int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            if (!isInRange(min, max, input))
                Toast.makeText(context, "Max Angle 90 Degrees", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }     
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

**EnterInformation Activity**

```
package com.TechDigy.parabolicmotion;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.InputFilter;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class EnterInformation extends Activity { 

    //Name the String which will be used to identify the file name of the SharedPreference
    public static final String REFS = "checkedornot";
    //final String[] names = new String[]{"DegreeLaunchInitialVelocity","DegreeLaunchInitialYVelocity","DegreeLaunchInitialXVelocity","InitialYVelocityInitialXVelocity"};
    boolean DegreeLaunchInitialVelocity,DegreeLaunchInitialYVelocity,DegreeLaunchInitialXVelocity,InitialYVelocityInitialXVelocity;
    boolean testout = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.next);
        //Reference the Edit Texts
        final EditText InitialVelocity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTInitialVelcity);
        final EditText DegreeOfLaunch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTDegreeOfLaunch);
        final EditText InitialYVelocity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTInitialYVelocity);
        EditText TimeOfFlight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTTimeOfFlight);
        EditText DistanceXDirection = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTDistanceTraveled);
        EditText PeakHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTPeakHeight);
        final EditText InitialXVelocity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTInitialXVelcity);
    //  if(DegreeOfLaunch.getText().toString().length() >2){
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Max Angle 90 Degrees", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //  }
        //Pass the context
        InputFilterMinMax context = new InputFilterMinMax(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: If there's a crash, please post the stack trace from logcat.  And there should be no problem calling Toast functions from any class, although you may need to be on the UI thread.

Comment: I second @GabeSechan, please post a stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try changing `getApplicationContext()` in the line

```
InputFilterMinMax context = new InputFilterMinMax(getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
EnterInformation.this
```

so, the line looks like,

```
InputFilterMinMax context = new InputFilterMinMax(EnterInformation.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same question but I solved it.!!
In the non-activity class , you just announce a "public static String".
Then in your MainActivity or other activity , you can directly use Toast.

In my case , I declare a non-activity class NoteDB.
so I declare  `public static String S` in the class .
(You can change S value in the class.
Then in my MainActivity , I announce

```
Toast(MainActivity.this, NoteDB.S ,TOAST.SHORT_LENTGH).show();
```

It works well.